# How do I grab trash from far under the desk in the 'Uprinsing' level?

Tags: viscera-cleanup-detail

In the 'Uprinsing' level of Viscera Cleanup Detail, there is an office scene with cubicles. Some of the desks have trash waaaaay far back. Try as I might, I haven't been able to grab it because I can't get close enough without losing sight of it (and unfortunately there is no bug where you can grab objects "through" the desk.)

Is there a trick to grabbing this stuff? I tried using the broom and the map and "whacking" it out of place, but I can't seem to reach with those implements. The only way to handle it that I've found so far is to incinerate it using the welder, but that then causes soot trails which I'd rather not deal with.

Is there a way to grab this out-of-reach junk without resorting to the welder?

Here's an example of one such piece of trash that I am having trouble grabbing. I've circled the item in red:

[image]

Comment: The welder only causes soot trails if you overheat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you can't reach it with your mop or anything, you can open the
>   developer console by pressing "~" and then typing "ghost" without the
>   quotes, then hitting enter.

Answer taken from a previous question asked on [steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/246900/discussions/0/530649887208769303/).